# How to integrate exp(-tan(x)^2)

Tags: integration

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} {e^{-\tan^2{x}}}dx
$$

The integral bound ranges from negative pi/2 to positive pi/2. I'd appreciate it if any one can provide an analytical expression and detailed derivation!

Comment: You know $\tan x$ blows up when $x$ approaches $\pi/2$ right? Thus, the integral diverges.

Comment: Sorry for that. I modified the expression. Right now it is correct

Comment: Still diverges. The bare minimum requirement for convergence would be that the integrand tended to 0 as $|x| \to \infty$. Which is not the case here.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: Your bare minimum (if that is indeed what you meant) is not required for the integral to exist. Think of a row of spike functions around each integer, of height $1$ and ever-decreasing width.

Comment: I confused the bound. The original form is exp(-x^2)/(1+x^2), the bound ranges from negative infinity to positive infinity. I substitute x with tan(x), therefore the bound is (-2*pi,2/pi)

Comment: Why didn't you ask the original integral ?

Comment: Since the integral exp(-x^2) is convergent, 1+x^2 is always larger than 1, the whole integral is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution $t=\tan x$, the integral becomes
$$
\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - t^2 } }}{{1 + t^2 }}dt}  = 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - t^2 } }}{{1 + t^2 }}dt}  = \pi e \operatorname{erfc} (1)=1.3432934\ldots,
$$
where $\operatorname{erfc}$ is the complementary error function (cf. 
http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.7.E1).

Comment: Dawson’s Integral is absolutely beyond my ken. Its defination in other place is quite different from showed in the link you provided. Could you please elaborate how the integral exp(-z^2)*R(z) is related to error functions and elementary functions. Thank you

Comment: What I gave you is a representation (and not the standard definition) of the complementary error function and not Dawson's integral (although they are related). For definitions, see https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2 Regarding your second question, you have to do partial fraction decomposition of $R(z)$ first. After that, you can use http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.7.i

Comment: Btw, I believe I answered your original question. There is no simpler answer, it is what it is.

Comment: Yeah, I have to admit this form is elegant. My original integral is right the first term you gave! The first equal sign is easy to yield. I can not understand the second equal sign. I'm really interested in how to derive it.

Comment: It follows by comparing it with http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.7.E1 when $z=1$.